# Interface to allow users to edit their Django model entries

Tags: django

The admin interface for editing (adding, deleting, changing) entries in the database is great.  I am working on a system, based on HTML forms, to allow users to edit information relevant to them in the database.  This will take a lot of work, and look less than professional.  Is there a standard way to allow a logged in user to use an administration-interface-like page to edit their (and only their) entries in a DB/model?

Comment: You can find a plenty of dashboard templates that you can reuse, or you can use django template inheritance to extend the default admin template and add whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do what you need by customizing django admin. In django admin you can define `get_queryset` method to restrict objects available for current user. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset, example there matches pretty well to your task

> One use case for overriding this method is to show objects owned by the logged-in user...

Comment: Be extremely careful about overriding Django's admin though. Once you upgrade to a new version of Django, you will break the templates because Django will inevitably change the other templates and view logic behind the supporting admin code that you didn't override. The biggest way in which this is evident is with styles. Django may change a CSS rule to point to a different class. You will then need to go change that class in every template you've overridden. This is an extremely long process as you basically have to dig into their source code.

Comment: Yes, customizing django admin templates can become complicated. However here I am talking only about overriding .get_queryset method - it is not related to templates. If you are happy with existing admin UI and your concern is mainly about restricting users to access only their objects, then customizing django admin sounds like a good solution.

Comment: You're right, idk why I though I saw templates. Yeah there's nothing wrong with overriding the python side of admin.